# How to get custom module on cms page

Tags: magento2.4.1, magento-2-commerce

I have created cms page name : contact us identifier: contact-us,

my layout:

```
<referenceBlock name="contactForm" template="Vendor_Block::form.phtml">
    <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Fields" template="Vendor_Block::fields.phtml" name="contact.fields" />
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="cms.contact.us">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">contact-us</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

I am getting following error on **localhost/magento/contact-us**

**We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this content.**

Comment: where are you loading these layout instructions?

Comment: To my cms page.

Comment: can you enable developer mode and see the logs also? maybe there is a more detailed stack trace

Answer (score 0):

You can call any custom module in cms page like below.

Please edit your cms page "contact-us" in admin and you can add layout directly from admin like :- https://prnt.sc/10p0oac

Please add like above.

Comment: I can't able to edit my layout xml section.

Comment: Why?Please check error logs for that.